# How do I convert a 14-30R to a 6-20R?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, 240v

I recently bought a home with a shop. The shop is full of these (I think it is a NEMA 14-30R):

[image]

But I have a compressor and band saw that need these (I think it is a 6-20R):

[image]

A picture of the box and labels:

[image]

[image]

I am going to be changing the receptacles that correspond with positions 15-18 and 45-48 in the box, so both 40 A breakers. I have done a little research and am fairly certain I understand in principle how to wire the 6-20R with the wires being used on the 14-30R, although I would welcome a sanity check. I plan to wire the hot poles with the red and black wires, ground to green with the bare copper, and cap the white wire and curl up in the box.

I gave it a try today and ran into an issue. The wire is a very heavy gauge stranded wire - not sure the size (6/3? 4/3? No idea). It is so large that I can’t wrap it around the screws and the small strands of the individual wires keep breaking.

My questions are:
1- is my understanding of the receptacle types correct?
2- Is my understanding of how to wire the smaller receptacle with the X/3 wire correct?
3- do I need to change the breakers from a 40A to a 20A or something else?
4- how do I connect such a large wire to a small receptacle? Do I need to use ring connector terminals or something?

Obviously I am not an electrician but I am not uncomfortable learning and doing. Just need some direction to see if I am in the ballpark. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

### Nothing easier, buy a *UL Listed* adapter.

The difference between a UL Listed one and a cheap Cheese one is that the UL-listed one will include a fuse to provide the protection a 20A device needs.

And is also made of thick enough contact bars, and the plastic is safety-rated to resist fire and not emit toxic smoke.

### 40A breakers don't play with 30A sockets

30A receptacles (and I agree those are NEMA 14-30) are not allowed to have anything but a 30A breaker.  NEC 210.21.

40A breakers require 50A sockets. (NEMA refuses to define 40A socket sizes, because they are running out of possible pin configurations).

Now motor rules are weird, and welder rules are *weirder*. Often when a circuit is *dedicated* to a particular motor or welder load, the breaker is allowed to be oversized (owing to small duty cycle on lighter-duty welders, and some motors have overcurrent protection onboard and don't need it from the breaker).  **However, this allowed oversizing does not apply to general-purpose receptacles**. The lack of "Miller M1234 Welder Only" stickers on these outlets makes them general-purpose receptacles.

### Use wire nuts or *ILSCO Mac Block Connectors* to step down

> gave it a try today and ran into an issue. The wire is a very heavy gauge stranded wire - not sure the size (6/3? 4/3? No idea). It is so large that I can’t wrap it around the screws and the small strands of the individual wires keep breaking.

Yes, that's going to happen.  Actually that indicates the wires are *larger than #10*, which is a blessing - they are legal on 40A breakers and only the socket was wrong.

- 8 AWG copper or 6 AWG aluminum is allowed 40A if it's NM or UF type cable.  Otherwise 8 AWG is allowed 50A.
- 6 AWG copper or 4 AWG aluminum is allowed 55A if NM or UF.  Otherwise 65A.
- 4 AWG copper is allowed 70A if NM or UF, otherwise 85A.
- The higher ampacity requires terminals rated 75°C thermal.
- Aluminum requires terminals *rated for aluminum* but is otherwise fine. ALL terminals should be torqued to spec, the difference is when *an aluminum* terminal burns up from mistorquing, aluminum gets blamed unfairly.
- NEMA 6-20 receptacles are not rated for aluminum, but most larger ones are.

Do not attempt to directly attach wires >#10 to a NEMA 6-20 receptacle.  You must *pigtail* to 12 AWG wires.  To pigtail, you can use a wire nut (if it is listed for wires that large) or for wires up to 6 AWG, you can use the ILSCO Mac Block Connector, which is a "mini Polaris".

The ILSCO Mac Block or larger Polaris is your only option for aluminum wire. Do not use purple wire nuts - they do not work.

### Questions

Honestly, I'd change the sockets to NEMA 14-50 type, and then use UL-Listed adapters to get NEMA 6-20 out of them.   Now to your questions:

> 1- is my understanding of the receptacle types correct?

Yes.

> 2- Is my understanding of how to wire the smaller receptacle with the X/3 wire correct?

Yes.

> 3- do I need to change the breakers from a 40A to a 20A or something else?

[image]

Comment: This seems like an easy fix. I like the idea of keeping the breakers I already have with the 14-50r. I am having a hard time finding the UL listed adapter with the 20 A fuse. I can only find the cheap ones, but I want the 20 A protection. I started on Amazon but have branched out and still can’t find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nijonew All the major marketplaces having 3rd party sellers, like eBay, DealExtreme, Wish.com, Etsy and Amazon Marketplace will be flooded with the cheap dangerous stuff from overseas.  A reputable RV supply ought to have a UL Listed one.  Note that the fuse is not visible or replaceable.

Comment: That helps a lot. I was able to find one once I started looking for RV plugs. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I changed the receptacle to the 14-50, got an adapter 14-50 to 6-20 with a 20A breaker, plugged my 12 AWG 16-ft extension cord into that, and then the band saw into that.  The breaker in the adapter trips immediately when I power up the bandsaw.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @nijonew Sounds like the breaker on the adapter is not tolerant of motor loads. Since you've already put the 20A breaker in the panel you might as well just change the outlet to NEMA 6-20. They make duplex 6-20 that takes the normal cover plate or domed cover.

Comment: That may be the case. For clarification the breaker that is tripping is the one in the adapter. I got two adapters because I need this in two locations and it does the same thing with both. So I still have the 40A breakers on the panel. This is the adapter that I purchased:      https://acworks.com/products/s1450cb620-1ft-50a-14-50p-plug-to-6-20-outlet?_pos=1&_sid=0dfe4d868&_ss=r

Comment: @nijonew Yes, I understood that. I would send it back as motor loads are perfectly reasonable loads.  (presuming your motor is not *broken*).   It is illegal to have a 20A breaker on a 50A socket, so go all-in on 20A, or all-in on 50a.

Comment: Gotcha. I think that is the next step. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the breakers to match the receptacles. There are certain exceptions (e.g., 15A receptacles on 20A breaker) but in general both the receptacles (exact match except where code allows specific exceptions) and the wire (wire can be larger than breaker but breaker can't be larger than wire).

As far as the receptacle terminals not accepting the large wire, that is not surprising. Get an appropriate size wire nut, such as an [Ideal WT54 Blue](https://www.idealind.com/us/en/shop/wingtwistr-wire-connector-model-wt54-blue-wingtwist-wt54.html) to pigtail a 12 AWG wire to the 6 AWG wire.

Comment: I will update the breakers and pigtail the wires. Thanks for the suggestions and for recommending a wire nut.

Comment: That looks like a beautiful installation.  People may beat me up for this, but what would so bad about buying a plugs that fits the existing 14-30R (30 amp, 240v) and the outlets needed for the band saw and compressor connected by a short length of 10/3 type SJ cable? I think the breakers are oversized for the 14-30R which is rated for 30 amps, but other than that, I'd leave everything intact and just go with a short (like 12") length of SJ to from the plug that fits the 14-30R to the one that feeds the tools.    I'd welcome friendly feedback.

Comment: Oversized breakers are bad, @GeorgeAnderson. And bad in code means "it killed enough people to get into code." It's neat and tidy and WRONG as shown, and Your suggested appoach does not address the WRONG. There are other ways that would be just as neat and tidy and RIGHT, one of which is in this answer. If keeping any at 40A, the correct receptacles should be swapped in on those.

Comment: If the breakers were resized for the 14-30Rs that would correct the WRONG. I did mention that the breakers were oversized.  

  Let's face it as we all know, breakers are to protect INSTALLED wiring, nothing more.  Devices plugged in or hard wired usually have much smaller wires. Good appliances and tools have their own over-current protection.  Most table lamps have 18ga wire that can be plugged into a 15 or 20 amp circuit. Extension cords are also often 16 or 18 ga (not that I approve of that). So I see a parallel with down sizing the breakers to match the outlets and make the adpator cord

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I very much disagree. The *primary* sizing determination for breakers is to match the wire. **But the device matters too.** A device may have wiring (internal for sure, but even the cable from the back of an oven to junction box, for example) that is smaller than the normal wiring required for NEC for a particular current rating. But that's OK as long as it is designed appropriately and approved by UL/ETL/etc. That being said, a device will have recommended breaker/circuit sizing based on expected current requirements and other design factors. That *must* be followed.

Comment: When there are no specific requirements, there are standard calculations (e.g., the continuous derate, very specific calculations for cooktops/ovens, etc.) that are used instead. So for example, when my electrician did my heavy-up, the AC outside unit was previously installed with a 30A circuit and 10 AWG wire. He checked the nameplate rating and determined that a 25A breaker was correct (16.1A x 1.25 = 20.125 - round up to 25A) and installed that in the new panel. No issue of the wiring (it could truly handle 30A) but right-sizing the breaker to fit the device.

Comment: When you plug a tool calling for a 20A breaker into a 40A or 30A outlet, A failure of the tool has not been tested by an NRTL (UL, ETL, etc.) to trip that size breaker, and it may merrily arc and burn without tripping, or for an excessively long time before tripping.

Comment: I'm going to be easy going on this.  So I respect the comments. I have a shop where my band saw, compressor, table saw, jointer, dust collector all operate at 240 / 20 amp circuits, all of them have over-current protection built into the motors and are socket/plug connected to the exact configuration for 240/20.  So I guess the only correct approach is to pigtail (as someone suggested) to be able to fit into the 240/20 amp outlet and downsize the breakers, pig-tailing on both ends probably, bc a 20 amp breaker probably won't take an 8 ga wire.   Maybe, maybe not, can't know until you try.

Comment: @George your idea won't work because you'd need a 20A fuse. **But UL approves adapters which do exactly that**.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your comment. I did say the breakers needed be downsized twice in 2 comments. So what are you saying?  I said pigtails might need to be used to fit the 20 amp breakers already, so what are you getting at?